# Prove $\frac{d_a}{h_a} +\frac{d_b}{h_b}+ \frac{d_c}{h_c}\geq\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: geometry, inequality

In a triangle $ \vartriangle ABC $, let $ h_a, h_b $ and $ h_c $ the atlitudes. Let $ D $ be the point where the inner bisector of $ \angle BAC $ cuts to the side $ BC $ and $ d_a $ is the distance from the $ D $ point next to $ AB $. The distances $ d_b $ and $ d_c $ are similarly defined. Show that:
$$ \dfrac {3} {2} \le \dfrac {d_a} {h_a} + \dfrac {d_b} {h_b} + \dfrac {d_c} {h_c} $$For what kind of triangles does the equality hold? 
I got this problem from my friend who also loves math, he says he found it in an old geomerty book, but he didn't tell me the source, unfortunately. He asked me to solve it, but to be honest I have no idea how to even start so I want to challenge you guys! Have fun with this amazing problem!

Comment: $d_a$ is the distance from $D$ to what?

Comment: To the side AB.

Comment: Like the perpendicular line on AB passing trough D.

Comment: Ok, so then next you want to define a point $E$ which is where the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ intersects the line $AC,$ right? But then it is not clear if $d_b$ is defined as the distance from $E$ to $AB$ or the distance from $E$ to $BC.$ Or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote the lengths $BC, CA, AB$ by $a,b,c$, then we have
$$\begin{align}
&S_{ABC} = S_{ABD} + S_{ACD} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot d_a\cdot c + \frac{1}{2}\cdot d_a\cdot b = \frac{1}{2}\cdot (b+c) \cdot d_a  \tag{1}\\
&S_{ABC} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot h_a \tag{2}\\
&(1)(2) \implies \frac{d_a}{h_a} = \frac{a}{b+c}\end{align}$$
We deduce then
$$RHS =  \frac{a}{b+c}+ \frac{b}{c+a}+ \frac{c}{a+b}$$
It's easy to prove that $RHS \ge 3/2$ as it is simply the [Nesbitt's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality)!

Comment: How did you get that  $a=b+c$?

Comment: There is probably a typo it should be  $(2) S_{ABC}=\frac{1}{2}ah_a$

Comment: I edited the mistake. Overall I think you solved it!